# Which branch to make a production package from in git flow

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree, git-flow

We are using git flow atm in our team, and we keep coming back to one question.

Which branch to make a package to deploy to production from?

If you make a release branch, and test it on test environment, then it kind of makes sense to take that same build, and just deploy that to production. But if I understood git glow correctly, what you should do is merge the release branch into master first (creates a tag with version number), and deploy a new build from the master branch to production. That also makes sense, because we have our build system append last commit SHA from the branch to the version number, so we can easily find what version is currently live and the tag corresponds to currently deployed code.

Now I know that the codebase from the release branch and master branch should be 1:1 exactly the same, but the fact is you are deploying an untested package to production, which makes some people on the team a bit nervous :P

So I thought I would ask here, what do you think is the best approach to this?

[image: figure 1]

Answer (score 0):

The code in your red circles should be identical. The master is only ever changed by merges, and nothing in there hasn’t reached the release branch at this point. If they were different (after that merge), that would indicate a process problem.

That said, the idea of the branches, in my understanding, is that you always release from the master. Where would the 0.2 release come from, otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

In that diagram, I would deploy to production from master after merging the release branch into master.

If doing that makes some on the team nervous, I would suggest that it may be due to a misunderstanding about how git handles merges.  When you merge the release branch into master with the commands:

```
git co master
git merge release-branch
```

The code in the two branches will be identical.  If you want to check that for yourself, you can run `git diff release-branch` and see any differences.